# Designer not loading in Visual Studio 2012 express edition on Windows 8 pro

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I recently installed Windows 8 64 bit Pro edition on my laptop.  After whcih I installed Visual Studio 2012 express edition on it, then I registered myself online for a developer liscence.

All set and done, now whenever I create a new project say "New Project > Windows Phone App"

My designer never loads, I get the following error messages...

> An Unhandled Exception has occurred,
>
> Click here to reload the designer

but no matter how many times I reload the designer or restart Visual studio or restart my laptop this error just wont go.

The entire exception I have [pasted here](http://pastebin.com/pU6FWHgy).

[image]

Please help me on this.

Comment: Document your problem properly.  Showing a screenshot of a half-scrolled message is not proper.

Comment: @HansPassant As far the half-scrolled message is concerned, I think you have NOT read the question properly, I have also given a link to the entire exception. Read the problem properly.

Answer (score 1):

I too had same issue when I installed Windows SDK for phone on **Windows 8 - 64bit** and Visual Studio 2012 Express. 
The solution that worked for me was:
 1. Uninstall VS 2012
 2. Uninstall all Silverlight components from Control panel -> Programs and features list.
 3. Install VS 2012 and SDK for Phone again

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It ended up being the Windows Firewall service was disabled. I use an alternate firewall, so I had that service disabled since I don't use it. Once I started the Windows Firewall service then turned off the firewall in the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security", the designer loaded and worked fine.